# schema in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know is there any software design the schema of oracle database?I mean if you work with Microsoft Sql U can easily design your database ,see the relation ,all tables and their fields,I want to know is there any software do same work in oracle.

I already try to find it in oracle Developer but nothing found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Oracle SQLDeveloper, I think it provides such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but [PowerDesigner](http://www.sybase.com/products/modelingdevelopment/powerdesigner), [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com), [ERWin](http://ca.com/erwin)... can be used for that.

Answer (score 0):

Toad also does this [Toad for Oracle - Freeware](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=toad%20download&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://toadworld.com/LinkClick.aspx?link=558&ei=kTfxTqjUIYiiiAeOnNi7AQ&usg=AFQjCNGBNNngoIbbKk1XlY2BMY-vv92nZg)